# Code first and drop ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I cant find in code first how to add id in sequence when one id was droped.
Example I have id 1,2,3,4,5 then I drop 3 and add another id but it has not 3 but 6 - how to change this. Help?

Ps. I use AddOrUpdate

Answer (score 0):

This is intended functionality.  Is there a particular reason your IDs have to be sequential??

This is pretty important for cascade deletion and referential integrity of relationships in EntityFramework.  For example, say you have a bunch of objects related to a person object w/ id of 3.  If you delete that person, then add another person w/ an id of 3, all of a sudden those other objects have a relationship with this new person object, which did not intend.

So really, don't be nervous about non sequential IDs, it should not affect your database lookup times.

if you have more questions comment below I'll try and explain.